# Custom Python Expression function defined as macro

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, expression, macro

Is it possible to define a custom Python Expression function like in the project macros?

Each time when I try to enable the macros and write any code, I get a security warning saying that `Python macros cannot currently be run` (as in the attached pictures).

[image]

[image]

I get a crash when attempting to run the last screenshot scenario.

Comment: On the right of the security warning there is an "Enable Macro" link did you try to click on that ? Also on the QGIS option (General  tab) what is the status of the "Enable macros" setting ?

Comment: In the first case ("Hello I am a macro" example) there is an error QgsMessangerBar.INFO . Once I deleted it the macro will work but the warning it will still appear. Whereas in the second case (with that function), the QGIS crashes when I click on "Enable Macro" link. 

The Enable macros is set to "Ask". Should it be set to "Always"?

What I am actually trying to do is to define in the macros a "Custom Python expression function" like to use it in the forms of the project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a custom expression function in a macro in this way:

[image]

Sample code:

```
from qgis.utils import qgsfunction
from qgis.core import QgsExpression

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='test', referenced_columns=[])
def my_sum(value1, value2, feature, parent):
    return value1 + value2

def openProject():
    pass

def saveProject():
    pass

def closeProject():
    QgsExpression.unregisterFunction('my_sum')
```

Note we unregister the created function when closing the project.

Therefore, the function `my_sum()` will only be available while your project is open, if the user accepts macros in her/his QGIS session.

---

Due to security issues that macros could trigger, your users will be asked for confirmation on running your macro, unless they have set the `Enable macros` option to `Always (Not Recommended)` in `Settings --> Options... --> General`.

Comment: Is the function automatically registered?

Comment: Yes, as soon as QGIS finds the `@qgsfunction` decorator, QGIS knows that's a function ready to be registered, and proceeds with its registration.

Comment: Thank you! It works indeed. I did not find this in the documentation. I wonder how you know about it.

Comment: Well, there are lots of things you know by practicing and by attempting alternate solutions. I've been working with PyQGIS since 2009! So, that's the secret :)